# Implement smooth transition to emulate car marker moving on the map

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to implement smooth transition to emulate car marker moving on the map. From current postion to selected position.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Provide a specific area that you are struggling with rather than asking for someone to write all of the code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if I suppose that you hadn't try anything, I give you a great method to achieve that .. just because I'm in a good mood

```
public static void animateMarker(final GoogleMap map, final Marker marker, final LatLng toPosition,
                          final boolean hideMarker) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Projection proj = map.getProjection();
    Point startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());
    final LatLng startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);
    final long duration = 500;

    final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration);
            double lng = t * toPosition.longitude + (1 - t) * startLatLng.longitude;
            double lat = t * toPosition.latitude + (1 - t) * startLatLng.latitude;

            marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));

            if (t < 1.0) {
                // Post again 16ms later.
                handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
            } else {
                if (hideMarker) {
                    marker.setVisible(false);
                } else {
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Enjoy it!